# Debugger error when parsing open graph object URL

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

OK, i'm falling at the first hurdle here and I'm sure it something obvious. I've created a little test open graph app on Facebook and knocked together a HTML page to act as the object URL (code below). This really is the most basic test, and I copied the code directly from FB.

When trying to parse this using the debugger I get the following error:

`Error Parsing URL  Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.`

Full HTML code of the web page is:

```
<html>
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# aform_garibaldi: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/aform_garibaldi#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="295505860505869" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="aform_garibaldi:drumming_style" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="http://www.appsformusicians.com" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="Sample Drumming Style" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="http://static.sqsp.com/static/4f666fb024ac1097e0151676/g/4f6d01ab24acad75aa703794/1332543916140/" /> 
</head>
<body>
Hello World.
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Their debug tool works 50% of time.

If you try to access it by pasting direct url in address bar like `.../debug/?q=http://...`
it shows you an error.

But if you click on debug button after this it will work.